# ios - perform database actions on background thread with FMDB

Tags: ios, sqlite, background-process, fmdb

I'm working with a local SQLITE db in an iOS (obj-c) project where we've chosen to use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). Please note I'm not interested in changing to Core Data or switching from FMDB to a different library.

Everything is working, but when we first run the app data is downloaded from our server, json is parsed, and then sorted into the local db. Due to the amount of info coming in this takes a good 30 - 40 seconds. Ideally this would be done in the background, but FMDB does not allow for this (at least as far as I can tell) as it may cause issues with the db data integrity.

Has anyone successfully used the FMDB library running all queries, inserts, etc on a background thread? I've tried simply wrapping actions in:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // ... query/insert/update/delete
    });
```

...but I end up with db integrity issues. Any tips or examples would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just curious. How did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@nawar - Sorry for not posting this sooner. I ended up using a single instace of FMDatabaseQueue (instead of FMDatabase) within the dispatch_async block. Works like a charm. The issues I was running into were due to using FMDatabase.

Comment: You should probably accept your own answer here, I think.

Comment: Could you post some code with your answer? That would be helpful for other people (like me) with the same problem.

Comment: Hi @Suragch FMDatabaseQueue will execute any operations you throw at it in order (serialized). So as long as you have a single instance of FMDatabaseQueue handling all calls to the db you can execute those calls within dispatch_async blocks. We ended up doing it using a singleton class "UserDatabase": instantiate the queue when this class is initialized, and wrap all operations in dispatch_async. Be warned I didn't do this for all functions so I can't vouch for that. We only used this at first launch to get a large number of initial rows into the db. Everything else was done synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

```html
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{  
       [self.dbQueue inTransaction:^(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback) {  
           BOOL result = YES;  
           for (int i = 500; i < 1000; i++) {  
               result =  [db executeUpdate:@"insert into testTable (name) values(?)",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name-%d",i]];  
               if (!result) {  
                   NSLog(@"break");  
                   *rollback = YES;  
                   break;  
               }  
           }  
             
       }];  
   });
```